# Flappy bird code not working - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to write a flappy bird game in javascript but it doesn't seem to work when I open it in my browser. the css works.
lines 147, 154, 31 and 160 in js all seem to be errors, but I do not understand how to fix them.

this is my html:

```js
var poles;
var bird;
var pole1;
var pole2;
var scoreSpan;
var speedSpan;
var speed;
var score;
var flapping;
var playing;
var scoreUpdated;
var gameArea;
var restartBtn;
var containerWidth;
var containerHeight;

function load() {
    bird = document.getElementById("bird")
    poles = document.getElementById("poles")
     pole1 = document.getElementById("pole-1")
     pole2 = document.getElementById("pole-2")
     scoreSpan = document.getElementById("score")
    speedSpan = document.getElementById("speed")
    gameArea = document.getElementById("game-area");
    restartBtn = document.getElementById("restart-btn");
    containerWidth = gameArea.clientWidth;
    containerHeight = gameArea.clientHeight;
}

function restart() {
    restartBtn.removeEventListener('click', restart);
    speed = 2;
    score = 0;
    scoreUpdated = false;
    flapping = false;
    playing = true;
    speedSpan.textContent = speed;
    scoreSpan.textContent = score;
    poles.forEach((pole) => {
        pole.style.right = 0;
    });
    bird.style.top = 20 + "%";
    gameLoop();
}

function update() {

    var polesCurrentPos = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(poles[0]).getPropertyValue("right"));

    if (polesCurrentPos > containerWidth * 0.85) {
        if (!scoreUpdated) {
            score += 1;
            scoreUpdated = true;
        }
        scoreSpan.textContent = score;
    }

    if (polesCurrentPos > containerWidth) {

        var newHeight = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
        // ùéðåé âåáä îåè
        pole1.style.height = 100 + newHeight + "px";
        pole2.style.height = 100 - newHeight + "px";

        polesCurrentPos = 0;

        speed += 0.25;
        speedSpan.textContent = parseInt(speed);
        scoreUpdated = false;
    }

    poles.forEach((pole) => {
        pole.style.right = polesCurrentPos + speed + "px";
    });

    let birdTop = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(bird).getPropertyValue("top"));
    if (flapping) {
        bird.style.top = birdTop + -2 + "px";
    } else if (birdTop < containerHeight - bird.clientHeight) {
        bird.style.top = birdTop + 2 + "px";
    }

    if (collision(bird, pole1) || collision(bird, pole2) || birdTop <= 0 || birdTop > containerHeight - bird.clientHeight) {
        gameOver();
    }
}

function gameOver() {
    window.console.log("game over");
    playing = false;
    restartBtn.addEventListener('click', restart);
}

function gameLoop() {
    update();
    if (playing) {
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }
}

function collision(gameDiv1, gameDiv2) {
    let left1 = gameDiv1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let top1 = gameDiv1.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let height1 = gameDiv1.clientHeight;
    let width1 = gameDiv1.clientWidth;

    let bottom1 = top1 + height1;
    let right1 = left1 + width1;
    let left2 = gameDiv2.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let top2 = gameDiv2.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let height2 = gameDiv2.clientHeight;
    let width2 = gameDiv2.clientWidth;
    let bottom2 = top2 + height2;
    let right2 = left2 + width2;

    if (bottom1 < top2 || top1 > bottom2 || right1 < left2 || left1 > right2)
        return false;
    return true;
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    var key = e.key;
    if (key === " " && playing) {
        flapping = true;
    }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stops weird behaviour where releasing space calls restart()
    var key = e.key;
    if (key === " " && playing) {
        flapping = false;
    }
});

gameArea.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    if (playing) {
        flapping = true;
    }
});

gameArea.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    if (playing) {
        flapping = false;
    }
});

restart();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Flappy Bird</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">
    <div id="game">
        <div id="game-area">
            <div id="bird"></div>
            <div class="pole" id="pole-1"></div>
            <div class="pole" id="pole-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="game-info">
            <p>Score:<span id="score">0</span></p>
            <button id="restart-btn">Restart</button>
            <p>Speed:<span id="speed">2</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are many errors in the js when I run it and I can't seem to understand why. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: From a glance: seems like you're adding an event listener before `gameArea` is initialized - the gameArea.addEventListener happens before load() has been called.

Comment: Adding to @Ezenhis also the restart function in the last line will be called before load(). Put all the event listeners and call to reload into the load function

Comment: Simply put all your code in the `load` function, so everthing will start executing when the page is truly loaded. Btw, you might want to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event for calling `load`, but that's not a critical problem (it should also work as it is now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is to move the event listeners into `load` and call `load` in your script:

```js
var poles;
var bird;
var pole1;
var pole2;
var scoreSpan;
var speedSpan;
var speed;
var score;
var flapping;
var playing;
var scoreUpdated;
var gameArea;
var restartBtn;
var containerWidth;
var containerHeight;

function load() {
  bird = document.getElementById("bird")
  poles = document.querySelectorAll(".pole")
  pole1 = document.getElementById("pole-1")
  pole2 = document.getElementById("pole-2")
  scoreSpan = document.getElementById("score")
  speedSpan = document.getElementById("speed")
  gameArea = document.getElementById("game-area");
  restartBtn = document.getElementById("restart-btn");
  containerWidth = gameArea.clientWidth;
  containerHeight = gameArea.clientHeight;

  gameArea.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    if (playing) {
      flapping = true;
    }
  });

  gameArea.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    if (playing) {
      flapping = false;
    }
  });
}

function restart() {
  restartBtn.removeEventListener('click', restart);
  speed = 2;
  score = 0;
  scoreUpdated = false;
  flapping = false;
  playing = true;
  speedSpan.textContent = speed;
  scoreSpan.textContent = score;
  poles.forEach((pole) => {
    pole.style.right = 0;
  });
  bird.style.top = 20 + "%";
  gameLoop();
}

function update() {

  var polesCurrentPos = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(poles[0]).getPropertyValue("right"));

  if (polesCurrentPos > containerWidth * 0.85) {
    if (!scoreUpdated) {
      score += 1;
      scoreUpdated = true;
    }
    scoreSpan.textContent = score;
  }

  if (polesCurrentPos > containerWidth) {

    var newHeight = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
    // ùéðåé âåáä îåè
    pole1.style.height = 100 + newHeight + "px";
    pole2.style.height = 100 - newHeight + "px";

    polesCurrentPos = 0;

    speed += 0.25;
    speedSpan.textContent = parseInt(speed);
    scoreUpdated = false;
  }

  poles.forEach((pole) => {
    pole.style.right = polesCurrentPos + speed + "px";
  });

  let birdTop = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(bird).getPropertyValue("top"));
  if (flapping) {
    bird.style.top = birdTop + -2 + "px";
  } else if (birdTop < containerHeight - bird.clientHeight) {
    bird.style.top = birdTop + 2 + "px";
  }

  if (collision(bird, pole1) || collision(bird, pole2) || birdTop <= 0 || birdTop > containerHeight - bird.clientHeight) {
    gameOver();
  }
}

function gameOver() {
  window.console.log("game over");
  playing = false;
  restartBtn.addEventListener('click', restart);
}

function gameLoop() {
  update();
  if (playing) {
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  }
}

function collision(gameDiv1, gameDiv2) {
  let left1 = gameDiv1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let top1 = gameDiv1.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let height1 = gameDiv1.clientHeight;
  let width1 = gameDiv1.clientWidth;

  let bottom1 = top1 + height1;
  let right1 = left1 + width1;
  let left2 = gameDiv2.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let top2 = gameDiv2.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let height2 = gameDiv2.clientHeight;
  let width2 = gameDiv2.clientWidth;
  let bottom2 = top2 + height2;
  let right2 = left2 + width2;

  if (bottom1 < top2 || top1 > bottom2 || right1 < left2 || left1 > right2)
    return false;
  return true;
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  var key = e.key;
  if (key === " " && playing) {
    flapping = true;
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Stops weird behaviour where releasing space calls restart()
  var key = e.key;
  if (key === " " && playing) {
    flapping = false;
  }
});

load();
restart();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Flappy Bird</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="game.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
        <div id="game-area">
            <div id="bird"></div>
            <div class="pole" id="pole-1"></div>
            <div class="pole" id="pole-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="game-info">
            <p>Score:<span id="score">0</span></p>
            <button id="restart-btn">Restart</button>
            <p>Speed:<span id="speed">2</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I replaced `poles = document.getElementById("poles")` with `poles = document.querySelectorAll(".pole")` to find all poles.

Comment: @IDK There is no HTML element with ID `poles`. `document.getElementById("poles")` returns `null`. `poles.forEach` and `poles[0]` cause errors because `poles` isn't an array.

Comment: so how can I address both poles otherwise?

Comment: @IDK you could use the class `pole`.